# using redux and redux-persist in react app: after submitting the form, store create a new and empty object

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-persist

I am using react, react-redux, and redux-persist in my application.
When I am submitting the form each time an array of nested object is created. The redux-persist seems working because the form data successfully can be saved in local storage. However, the most confusing part is that I do not know why nested objects created each time.

[image]

**Store**

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' // defaults to localStorage for web
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import rootReducer from './reducers'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}

// const initialState = {}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

const configureStore = () => {
  let store = createStore(persistedReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware()))
  let persistor = persistStore(store)
  return { store, persistor }
}
export default configureStore;
```

**actions**

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid' 
export const ADD_ARRAY_CHALLENGE = "ADD_ARRAY_CHALLENGE";



export const addArrayChallenge = name => ({
  type: "ADD_ARRAY_CHALLENGE",
  id: uuidv4(),
  name
});
```

**reducer**

```
import {ADD_ARRAY_CHALLENGE} from './../actions'


export const arrayFormReducer = (state = [] , action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ADD_ARRAY_CHALLENGE:
      return [
        state, {
          id: action.id,
          name: action.name
        }
      ]
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

**combineReducer**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import {arrayFormReducer} from './arrayFormReducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  arrayForm: arrayFormReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

I really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Note the spread of the previous state:

```js
case ADD_ARRAY_CHALLENGE:
    return [
        ...state, 
        {
            id: action.id,
            name: action.name
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are returning state object in reducer, its nesting itself thats creating the nested object. Use spread operator inside each CASE. It will add all other state properties in the returning object, and after that you can add new / override state

```
import {ADD_ARRAY_CHALLENGE} from './../actions'


export const arrayFormReducer = (state = [] , action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ADD_ARRAY_CHALLENGE:
      return [
        ...state, {
          id: action.id,
          name: action.name
        }
      ]
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```